# Would it be possible to Merge 2 onEdit Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, timestamp, dropdown

Would it possible to merge them in one script as I don't know much about coding and would also be possible to add the username/editor's name automatically in the next cell when someone made an edit to the sheet?**

Tried pasting the code here but I am having a hard time doing it.

Here's what I am working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16NBcSAyeUgVQVc4MfWJLSBBN_GqzP9YmdQPAf5oPJuI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: Google tells me that _File is in owner's trash_: is this issue still relevant to you?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it's possible

Just rename your two functions to something else then `onEdit` and call them both from a single `onEdit` function.

Sample:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  one(e);
  two(e);
}
function one(e){
  ...
}
function two(e){
  ...
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! it's working now!! Thanks so much!!